# Do you see any reason for segmentation fault out of that code segment?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I try to initialize a new linked list with head pointer of another list. I defined that constructor

```
template <typename dataType>
List<dataType>::List(Node* aHead){
    size = 0;
    head = aHead;
    for(Node* cur = head; cur != NULL; cur = cur->next){
        size++;
    }
}
```

even it constructs the list, it indicates segmentation fault at the end  of execution. If you want to share some help on more, you might look at the [whole code](http://pastebin.com/uuU6Bn0T).

This is the current output of the main function

```
6 4 5 
List size : 3
6 4 5 
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: if you looked the main function from the link you would see that aHead is defined as another list's head pointer.

Answer (score 1):

In your constructor, all you're doing is making a copy of the pointer:

```
head = aHead;
```

That doesn't give you a new list with a new set of nodes. It simply gives you a new list pointing to the **same set of nodes**.

In your destructor, you're destroying the list using repeated calls to `remove(0)`, which in turn deletes each node, like so:

```
delete cur;
```

That presents a big problem, because both lists try to delete the same nodes. The first list to be destroyed is fine, but the second is calling delete on a invalid memory location.

The solution is to change your constructor to actually make a copy of the Nodes. That's more complicated than it sounds, because you have to copy **all** of the nodes, not just the head. It also relies on your `Node` class having a copy constructor as well.

Comment: Pointing same set of nodes is my intention, so in that term it works correctly. The problem is the segmentation fault I indicated above. I do not want to have a copy constructor.

Comment: If the two lists are pointing to the same set of nodes, you **will** have a problem somewhere. It may or may not be what's causing your current segfault, but it will definitely cause one eventually unless you fix it.

Comment: givan aHead is a pointer to newly created list but its class not defined as List. I try to embrace it with List class by setting its head ptr to aHead. So there is only one list class at the end